# How do you set a currency label to show smaller font size for cents?

Tags: swift, fonts, label, currency

I have a list of labels with dollar amounts (example: $1,526.69).

How do I set the font size for the cents (in this case, the 69 cents) to be smaller than the whole dollars?

Like the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mutable attributed string in your label. You will need to find the range of the cents in your string set a smaller font size and increase add a baseline offset to the cents:

```
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$1,526.69")
if let range = mutableAttributedString.string.range(of: #"(?<=.)(\d{2})$"#, options: .regularExpression) {
    mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 5),.baselineOffset: 5],
        range: NSRange(range, in: mutableAttributedString.string))
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. Then you set: ```myTextLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString```. (I didn't know this so I'm putting it here for those who may not know.)